# Construct a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ and $f_n \to 1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I need to construct a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ for each $n$ and $f_n \to 1$ pointwisely not uniformly.

I have been trying for 2 hours, the condition that $f_n \to 1$ is easy and being continuous is also easy, but the condition that $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ is rather difficult for me. I can only construct decreasing ones.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I'd recommend a variant of $\arctan nx$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson well $\tanh(nx)$ requires even less effort :D

Comment: if $f_n\to 1$ point wise and not uniformly but $f_n$ are decreasing, you can use $2-f_n$ instead.

Comment: What about $f_n=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: @dan_fulea, your example converges uniformly

Comment: @bbw Oh, thanks, i got the bad message from the OP, had to read till the end... sorry

Answer (score 3):

You may take $f_n$ to be $1$ on $[0,n]$, decrease linearly from $1$ to $0$ on $[n,n-1]$, and be $0$ on $[n+1, +\infty[$. The formula is

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \le n\\
1 - (x-n) & \text{if } n < x \le n+1 \\
0 & \text{if } n+1 < x\\
\end{cases}$$

The sequence $(f_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is increasing, and converges point wise $f_n \to 1$, but not uniformly (what is $\|f_{n}-1\|_{\infty}$ ?).

Comment: Oh right ! Thanks for spotting my mistake !

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\cos {\pi x\over 2n}&,\quad 0\le x\le n\\0& ,\quad x>n\end{cases}$$and you're done.

Comment: Nice idea ! I think it would also work by replacing $x \mapsto \cos(\pi x /2)$ with any continuous function $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ that decreases from $1$ do $0$ (you may for example take $1-\frac{x}{n}$ on $[0,n]$)